# efficient way to find gcd pairs for an upper bound number, 10000 in java

Tags: java

I want to find pairs  having GCD=1 upto a certain number, say 10000.
I am using 2 nested loops and calling a method with long parameters.
but code is running damn slow, any efficient approach is required.
Thanks

```
class FastGCD {

    public static long GCD(long a, long b) {

        return (b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b));
    }

    public static void main(String ah[]) throws Exception{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int cases = 0;

        long number = 0, output = 0;
        try {
            cases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= cases; i++) {
            try {
                number = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < number; k++) {

                    if (FastGCD.GCD(j, k) == 1)
                        {
                        //System.out.println("here"+j+","+k);
                        output++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have

Comment: Check [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422830/generating-all-coprime-pairs-within-limits) on *Mathematics StackExchange*.

Comment: post edited.. code attached.. @SteveBenett

Answer (score 2):

Many of these problems are already solved.

Check wikipedia or other sources for algorithms.

One of this is [the Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

though more exist

To generate the co prime numbers (Which you seem to want)

[This Should help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime#Generating_all_coprime_pairs)

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm is used to check wether two numbers are mutually prime, it does not generates coprime pairs and is not an alternative to the two nested loops.

Comment: The ternary trees (second link) is however a better suited approach.

Answer (score 0):

> **Generating all coprime pairs**
>
> All pairs of coprime numbers m, n can be arranged in a pair of disjoint complete
>   ternary trees, starting from (2,1) (for even-odd or odd-even pairs)
>   or from (3,1) (for odd-odd pairs).
>
> The children of each vertex
>   (m,n) are generated as follows:
>
> Branch 1: (2m-n,m)
>
> Branch 2: (2m+n,m)
>
> Branch 3: (m+2n,n)
>
> This scheme is exhaustive and non-redundant with no
>   invalid members.
>
> from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime#Generating_all_coprime_pairs)

These two ternary trees can easily be build in Java (one starting with (2,1), the other one starting with (3,1)).
You can put your upper bound inside the generation function.

It will be much more efficient than your brute-force approach.